# biginteger library compatible with mpi (message passing interface)

Tags: c++, mpi, biginteger

I'm searching for a `BigInteger` library that is compatible with the usual suspects of the `Message Passing Interface` standard, such as `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send` and `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv`.

Unfortunately MPI also stands for *multi precision integer*, so most search results actually do not match. Several attempts to search this with google using similar queries did not reveal any implementation, but surely someone already did that. So basically the question is: does anyone know an implementation of mpi compatible with MPI?

Answer (score -2):

in theory ANY big integer library would be compatible but with some caveats.

The big integer library would not be one of MPI's standard [data types](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_byte), MPI_INT MPI_DOUBLE exc exc...

One approach is to serialize your biginteger into bytes, send/recv it as MPI_BYTE then convert it back

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this is helpful. Obviously big integers have to be serialized, that's just how things work with MPI::Send. The problem with that is that it is not interchangeable with say `int` and that one need to communicate the size of the datatype first. Surely someone built a framework for that, therefore my question. I don't want to mess with the bigInteger library myself.

Comment: @stefan There seems to be no generic framework. The same solution suggested above was also mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201522/how-can-i-pass-long-and-or-unsigned-integers-to-mpi-arguments