# I want to avoid data size limit in MPI (int count parameter)

Tags: mpi

We face with a data size problem using MPI.

In the following, for instance,

```
MPI_Allreduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count, ...,
```

the data type of count is limited to `int`.

However, our problem needs it to be `long long int`, which makes a problem.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicate data with \`count\` value close to \`INT\_MAX\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611630/communicate-data-with-count-value-close-to-int-max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401248

https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI implements a number of solutions. See README for details. Short answer is that you need to use derived datatypes.

If BigMPI doesn't meet your needs, please let me know (I'm the primary author).

Comment: Actually, I found out your code yesterday and already tried using a part of your code. It worked well. Thanks!